# Mesh is penetrating each other

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I have a body/character that I've attached some clothes to. I've rigged and weight painted the clothes and it seems to work in some places other not so well. So I tried to fix it with no luck. I've re-rigged and weight painted it again but I still have some problems with some of the mesh penetrating another one. So what do I do to prevent this? Please help!

[image: screenshots of the problem]

Comment: Have you considered "cheating" and removing or masking out the character mesh (or copy of) when under the clothes?

Comment: Do the faces in the clothes align(or run parallel ) with the faces in your body mesh?  if you have an edge in the leg, moving accross a face in the clothes, it would cause this behavior.